# Sending variable as argument using escape character is not working

Tags: javascript, arguments

sending variable as argument is not working in this code

```js
document.write('<input type="text" id="argument">');
var testArg = document.getElementById('argument').value;
document.write('<button onclick="sendArg(\'' + testArg + '\')">Display Argument</button>');
document.write('<p id="displayArg"></p>')

function sendArg(recArg) {
  document.getElementById('displayArg').innerHTML = recArg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value to the `testArg` variable as soon as you've written the `input` element. Since there is no `value` attribute, its value is an empty string.

If you want to get the value *at the time the button is clicked* then you need to read it from the DOM in the event handler that deals with the button click.

You should avoid using `document.write` too. Aside from the side effect of wiping out the existing document, trying to escape strings for HTML and JS manually is painful (what if the user wrote `"` or `'` in the input? That would break the HTML you were trying to generate).

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
var inp = document.createElement("input");
var bt = document.createElement("button");
bt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Display Argument"));
bt.type = "button";
bt.addEventListener("click", sendArg);

function sendArg(event) {
  p.innerHTML = inp.value;
}

document.body.appendChild(inp);
document.body.appendChild(bt);
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: I understood the code above you have written and most of it I know also. I want to know why my code is not working. Can you please write solution using my code only

Comment: @AseemSharma — I explained why it isn't working in the first paragraph (and how to fix it in the second). The third paragraph explains why your entire approach is doomed to failure. You need to change your approach.

Answer (score -1):

You are using single quotes to open the HTML attribute, you can't use it as JavaScript String because you'll be closing the HTML attribute, use double quotes:

```js
document.write("<button onclick="sendArg(\''+testArg+'\)">Display Argument</button>");
```

Comment: "You are using single quotes to open the HTML attribute" — They are not: `onclick="`

Comment: Your own code example throws the error:   "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",